# In R: How to find a first occurance of an specific element in a vector, based on a starting point in another vector

Tags: r

I have some big datasets containing distance information (distance), and acceleration information (a) on roads. I would like to start looking from a specific point in the dataset (say, a crossing) and look backwards, and forwards, to find zero acceleration.

For example this database:

```
df <- data.frame("distance" = seq(0, 250, by=10), "a" = c(-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1))
```

When my specific point in the distance is 133 (say, there is the crossing), I would like to find the answer 100 for the point where no deceleration is measured before, and the answer 150 for the point after.

When using for instance which(max()) or which(min()), this will produce wrong answers, because of multiple occurances of 0.

Does anyone have a good workflow or idea on how to procede?

Kind regards,
Johan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `rleid` to create a grouping column based on the logical vector (`a==0`).  This will create a grouping index when the adjacent value is not equal to the previous value.  Then `filter` the groups where `all` the 'a' values are 0 or the number of rows are greater than 1. Apply `findInterval` to get the closest index match between the 133 and 'distance' to `slice` the rows and `pull` the 'distance' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
df %>% 
   group_by(grp = rleid(a == 0)) %>% 
   filter(all(a == 0) & n() > 1) %>% 
   slice(findInterval(133, distance) + 0:1) %>%
   pull(distance)
#[1] 100 150
```

Comment: Thanks! This seems to work indeed. Could you explain a bit further, so I understand what is going on? Wat does rleid() do? Why ad n() >1? And what does + 0:1 doe in slice()?